# Xcode - Clang error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, clang

I've been working on this C++ programming assignment in Xcode for a while, and am encountering a persistent clang error in my code:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Card::print()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"Card::getBookID()", referenced from:
  checkOutBook(Book*, Card*, int, int) in main.o
"Card::getCardID()", referenced from:
  checkOutBook(Book*, Card*, int, int) in main.o
  checkInBook(Book*, Card*, int, int) in main.o
"Card::setBookID(int)", referenced from:
  checkOutBook(Book*, Card*, int, int) in main.o
  checkInBook(Book*, Card*, int, int) in main.o
"Card::Card(int, char*, char*)", referenced from:
  createCard(int, char*, char*) in main.o
"Card::Card()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After several frustrating hours of searching the forums trying to chase it down, I'm hoping someone can help me. My code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Card
{
private:
char cardName[30];
char phoneNumber[15];
int CardID;
int BookID;

public:
Card();
Card(int c, char n[], char p[]);
void setBookID(int b);
int getBookID();
int getCardID();
void print();
};

class Book
{
private:
int BookID;
int CardID;
char title[30];
char author[10];

public:
Book();
Book(int b, char t[], char a[]);
void setCardID(int c);
int getCardID();
int getBookID();
void print();
};

Book::Book()
{
BookID = 0;
CardID = 0;
title[0] = '\0';
author[0] = '\0';
}

Book::Book(int b, char t[], char a[])
{
BookID = b;
strcpy(title, t);
strcpy(author, a);
CardID = 0;
}

void Book::setCardID(int c)
{
CardID = c;
}

int Book::getCardID()
{
return CardID;
}

int Book::getBookID()
{
return BookID;
}

void Book::print()
{
cout << title << endl
<< author << endl
<< "Book ID: " << BookID << endl;
if(CardID == 0)
{
    cout << "Not Checked Out." << endl << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Checked Out to: " << CardID << endl << endl;
}
}






//Begin

void ShowMenu();
void checkOutBook(Book books[], Card cards[], int numBooks, int      numCards);
void checkInBook(Book books[], Card cards[], int numBooks, int     numCards);
Card createCard(int cardID, char name[], char phone[]);

int main()
{
int command = 0;

// declare an array of 20 cards
Card cards[20];
int numCards = 0;

// declare an array of 20 books
Book books[20];
int numBooks = 0;

// declare a file pointer and open the cards file
ifstream cardInput("cards.txt");
if(!cardInput)
{
    cout << "ERRORL Cannot open file 'cards.txt'" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout << "Reading cards.txt file. . ." << endl;
char name[25];
char phone[15];
int cardID = 0;
char junk[25];

// read the next line from the file
cardInput.getline(name, 25, ','); // Read first person's name

while (cardInput)
{
    cardInput.getline(junk, 5, ' '); // Read past blank space
    cardInput.getline(phone, 15, ',');
    cardInput.getline(junk, 5, ' ');
    cardInput >> cardID;
    cardInput.getline(junk, 5, '\n');


    // Create a card
    cards[numCards] = createCard(cardID, name, phone);
    numCards++;

    cardInput.getline(name, 25, ',');
}
// create a card and store it in the array of cards


// declare a file pointer and open the books file
ifstream bookInput("books.txt");
if(!cardInput)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file 'books.txt'" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout << "Reading books.txt file. . ." << endl;
char title[25];
char author[15];
int bookID = 0;
char junk2[25];

// read the next line from the file
bookInput.getline(title, 25, ','); // Read title of first book

while (bookInput)
{
    bookInput.getline(junk2, 5, ' '); // Read past blank space
    bookInput.getline(author, 15, ',');
    bookInput.getline(junk2, 5, ' ');
    bookInput >> bookID;
    bookInput.getline(junk2, 5, '\n');

    // create a books and store it in the array of books


    // display main menu
    ShowMenu();
    cin >> command;

    while(command != 0)
    {
        switch(command){
            case 1:  // Show all Library Cards
                for(int i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
                {
                    cards[i].print();
                }
                break;
            case 2:  // Show all Books
                for(int i=0; i < numBooks; i++)
                {
                    books[i].print();
                }
                break;
            case 3:  // Check out a Book
                checkOutBook(books, cards, numBooks, numCards);
                break;
            case 4:  // Check in a Book
                checkInBook(books, cards, numBooks, numCards);
                break;
            case 5:  // Create a new Library Card
                cout << "Enter your name: ";
                cin.getline(junk, 2, '\n');
                cin.getline(name, 25, '\n');

                cout << "Enter your phone number: ";
                cin.getline(phone, 15, '\n');

                cout << "Enter the card ID: ";
                cin >> cardID;

                // Create card and store it in the next array location
                cards[numCards] = createCard(cardID, name, phone);
                numCards++;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "ERROR: Values must be between 1 and 5." << endl;
        }

        ShowMenu();
        cin >> command;
    }



}

return 0;
}


void ShowMenu()
{
cout << "=====[ M A I N   M E N U ]=====" << endl;
cout << "   1. Show all Library Cards   " << endl;
cout << "   2. Show all Books           " << endl;
cout << "   3. Check out a Book         " << endl;
cout << "   4. Check in a Book          " << endl;
cout << "   5. Create a New Library Card" << endl;
cout << "   6. Exit the System          " << endl;
}

void checkOutBook(Book books[], Card cards[], int numBooks, int numCards)
{
int card = 0, book = 0;
int cardid = 0, bookid = 0;

// Enter Card ID
cout << "Enter your Card ID: ";
cin >> cardid;

// Find Card ID
while(card < numCards && cardid != cards[card].getCardID())
{
    card++;
}
// If not found, return
if(card == numCards)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Invalid Card ID. Create a new card before retrying." << endl;
    return;
}

// If found, does the person have a book checked out?
// If yes, return
if (cards[card].getBookID() != 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR: You already have a book checked out. Please return    it first before retrying." << endl;
    return;
}

// Card validated!


// Enter Book ID
cout << "Enter the Book ID: ";
cin >> bookid;

// Find Book ID
while(book < numBooks && bookid != books[book].getBookID())
{
    book++;
}
// If not found, return
if(book == numBooks)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Invalid Book ID. Try another book." << endl;
    return;
}

// If found, is it checked out?
// If yes, return
if(books[book].getCardID() != 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR: This book is already checked out. Come back later." << endl;
    return;
}
// Book validated!


// Check out the book
cards[card].setBookID(bookid);
books[book].setCardID(cardid);

}



void checkInBook(Book books[], Card cards[], int numBooks, int numCards)
{
int card = 0, book = 0;
int cardid = 0, bookid = 0;

// Enter Card ID
cout << "Enter your Card ID: ";
cin >> cardid;

// Find Card ID
while(card < numCards && cardid != cards[card].getCardID())
{
    card++;
}
// If not found, return
if(card == numCards)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Invalid Card ID. Create a new card before retrying." << endl;
    return;
}
// Card found!

// Enter Book ID
cout << "Enter the Book ID: ";
cin >> bookid;

// Find Book ID
while(book < numBooks && bookid != books[book].getBookID())
{
    book++;
}
// If not found, return
if(book == numBooks)
{
    cout << "ERROR: Invalid Book ID. Try another book." << endl;
    return;
}

// Check out the book
cards[card].setBookID(0);
books[book].setCardID(0);
}


Card createCard(int cardID, char name[], char phone[])
{
Card temp(cardID, name, phone);
return temp;
}
```

I realize it's incredibly lengthy, but I'm in a last ditch effort. I'm still really new to C++ and Xcode, am I'm not good at navigating the menus to try all of the fixes people have suggested on other posts. The extent of my knowledge with the clang error is that it could mean a duplicate function somewhere or some setting being wrong. I really appreciate any and all advice on this, thank you in advance.

Comment: The methods in your declaration of the `Card` class have not been defined.

Comment: Would this different than the way Book class is set up? My professor does online videos to follow along to and this is how he set it up, though his is without error there. Thank you for the help!